# Publish only Module in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, asp.net-web-api, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I'm working in Orchard project & i want to implement WebApi in my project so that I plan to create one WebApi related separate module which handles all the database related code & returns the result to the other modules as well third party calls.

But for implementing like this, how can i publish my rest of the application at one place & the WebApi related module at another place.

Comment: A module only runs in an Orchard application. Why would you place it somewhere else? You can just include it in your application and let your other modules make use of it, as well as third parties

Comment: Yes, right now going through the same as you suggested but if there are any changes required in Api then only need to publish the Api related module for that no need to disturb whole project & republish it.

In just simple MVC we creating the simple two different project & create dependency to APi to Client & make Api available to clients so that i think if it's possible over here then i go through that way.

Comment: If you don't need Orchard, then don't use it :) Create a separate app, for the purpose you desire.

Comment: No I have implemented almost in Orchard so want to go through it only but its ok for me. I just want to know is there any way to do so.

Comment: I think this is a really good question. Often times your local machine will only have a 'vanilla' version of Orchard with your own custom Module for testing purposes. You can't just publish the project because it would override the online website which might have other customizations, modules enabled, ... The answer given by @SzymonSeliga has been very helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run Orchard Modules without Orchard. If you want to separate site publishing from module publishing, you can update single modules. To do this you need to package you module and then  upload and install it to the site. Either by Admin Dashboard or Orchard Command-line.

On how to package a module and install it with Orchard Command-line check the Orchard Doc's [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Packaging-and-sharing-a-module)

You can also upload the module package via Orchards Admin Dashboard. Check [this](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Installing-and-upgrading-modules) Orchard Doc to accomplish this.

**Important! Remember to update your module's version in Module.txt manifest file.** Otherwise the update won't work.